# Trigger an event at end of onchange for input type range

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger an event or detect the end of onchange event for input type range.

```
$('.slider').on('change',function(e){
      console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

Now this will return a number of console logs when I start dragging the range input. I wanted to get the value at the end of onchange event. How to achieve this ?

Thank you ;)

Comment: try focusout event

Comment: Hi @guradio , i tried your solution but this event triggers when i click outside the range bar. I wanted to get it on release of the range input

Comment: This is already how the range input works....? https://jsfiddle.net/jvvL63s0/ Note that the text `input` is only updated when the handle is released after dragging

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , Thank you. There is a slight delay for the input box to update the value. But this works fine.

Comment: I haven't changed anything though - that's your own code. All I did was show the value in another input

Comment: i think on change event is enough for to get last values  @GururajBhandarkar

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Haha yes ! Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: @JYoThI, Yes onchange event will fetch me the last value but it will also give me values through which it was slided. The only work around for this is to put the value in a text box and then fetch it from there I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey Gururaj you can try [`debounce`](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) function. It delays the firing of your event handler so you can get your input value at the end of `onchange` event as you want it. [Lodash has a implementation of the debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) function you can use.

```
$range.on('change', _.debounce(function() {
  $display.text($(this).val());
}, 250));
```

Here's a little [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dawchihliou/p1yxbxzx/) for you.

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you :) This works exactly like i wanted. Firing after the end of change event. Cheers ;)

Comment: Nice not a problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 6):

you can use `mousedown` and `mouseup`  something like this

```js
var prevValue = 0;
$('.slider').on('change',function(e){
      
});
// mouse down to check for previous value
$('.slider').on('mousedown',function(e){
      prevValue = $(this).val();
});
// mouse up when the mouse up from the slider with end value
$('.slider').on('mouseup' , function(){
    var ThisValue = $(this).val();
    if(ThisValue !== prevValue){  // check new value with previous value
     alert('Value Changed');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100"/>
```

For complete answer as an example above using `mouseup` and `mousedown` events this is if you need to compare a previous value with new value and like [JYoThI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5933698/jyothi) said *i think on change event is enough to get last values of range*

***Additional Information*** you can use `input` event if you need to update the div value on realtime

**Working Demo**

```js
$('.slider').on('change',function(e){
      console.log($(this).val());
});

//update sliderCount div with real time value
$('.slider').on('input',function(e){
      $('.sliderCount').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="slider" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100"/>
<div class="sliderCount">50</div>
```

Comment: i think on change event is enough for to get last values of range

Comment: Thank you Yousef. This workaround also works fine :)

Comment: @GururajBhandarkar you're totally welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @JYoThI you're right .. I'm not expert with input type range but I think `mouseup` and `mousedown` may be can do another job in the future .. may be getting the previous value and compare it with the new one .. something like that .. anyway Thanks a lot and have a great day :-)