# Get value from input range slider only when mouse release

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an angular 4 project. The code below helps me to get the real time value from slider when user slides between 0 and 1. Each time user slides,  *applycontrol* function triggers because of ngModelChange.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Brightness" type="range" 
(ngModelChange)="applyControl($event)" min="0"
           max="1" [step]="0.01" class="slider">
```

All i want to run another function inside *applycontrol* function only when user release the mouse after slide.

```
  applyControl(value) {
     console.log('Brightness:', value);
   }
```

Comment: This discussion solves my issue using Jquery. But how to achieve the same in angular 4 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065123/trigger-an-event-at-end-of-onchange-for-input-type-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `change` event.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Brightness" type="range" 
(change)="applyControl($event)" min="0"
           max="1" [step]="0.01" class="slider">
```

Comment: (change) triggered only when user release the slider. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change this function:

```
applyControl(value) {
     console.log('Brightness:', value);
   }
```

to

```
 applyControl(event:any) {
         console.log('Brightness:', event.target.value);
       }
```